# Maximum regions chords can divide a circle

Tags: circles

**What is the maximum number of regions into which *n* chords can divide a circle?**

I have gotten all my data, and I am having trouble with writing the equation.

[image]

I notice that the first difference is not constant, but the second difference is. The second difference is +1. I know that this is a quadratic equation.

I believe the equation is *r*=(*n*(*n*+1))/2, if *r*=maximum number of regions. However, using that equation I am off by 1. Where am I going wrong? Can someone walk me through how to write the equation correctly?

Comment: Why not just add $1$? I'm not sure if this equation is right, but $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1$ seems to fit that data set. If you want to prove it, you might do some kind of induction argument.

Comment: So I figured out an equation that does work, r=(n(n-1)/(2+1), but why does it work?

Comment: The formula should be $ \frac {n^2 +n +2}{2}$ as pointed out above. See: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleDivisionbyLines.html for more information.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused as to how we got from f(2)=2+f(1) to f(n)=n+f(n-1).

Comment: As a general rule in life, whenever dealing with integer sequences, always check [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A000124). It contains a wealth of information and references.

Answer (score 2):

when you add the kth line there already exist k-1 lines so there are at most k-1 new intersections you can create. these k-1 new intersections create k portions on the kth line hence k new regions in the circle so $f(k)=f(k-1)+k$. summing both sides from k=1 to n yields $f(n)=f(0)+n(n+1)/2$. since $f(0)=1$ we have $f(n)=(n^2+n+2)/2$